# Spring Data JPA Specification Manyto One relationship

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two entities in Spring Data JPA:

```
User--->* TaxPayment
```

The goal is to get the all the taxpayments related to user_id:

User.java

```
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

..........
}
```

TaxPayment.jva

```
public class TaxPayment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "payment_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate paymentDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "amount", precision=10, scale=2, nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @Column(name = "reference")
    private String reference;

    @ManyToOne
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }..
}
```

I dont wan't to have oneTOMany Annotation from User.java and the column mapped in the Taxpayment as user_id.

Specification class as follows:

```
final class TaxPaymentSpecification {
    
    private TaxPaymentSpecification(){
        
    }
    
    static Specification<TaxPayment> hasUser(Long userId){
        return new Specification<TaxPayment>() {
            
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<TaxPayment> arg0, CriteriaQuery<?> arg1,
                    CriteriaBuilder arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Root<TaxPayment> root = arg0;
                Subquery<Long> subqry =  arg1.subquery(Long.class);
                Root<User> user =  subqry.from(User.class);
                
                final Join<User,TaxPayment> taxpays = root.join("user");
                
                subqry.select(taxpays.<Long> get("user_id"));
                
                subqry.where(arg2.equal(user.<Long> get("id"),userId));
                return arg2.in(arg0.get("user_id")).value(subqry);

           }
        };
        
    }
}
```

Is specification is correct or wrong as per my goal to get all the TaxPayment related to user_id?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use subquery if you already know the userId, which will be the value of user_id in TaxPayment table:

```
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<TaxPayment> arg0, CriteriaQuery<?> arg1, 
        CriteriaBuilder arg2) {
  return arg2.equal(arg0.get("user_id"), userId);
}
```